# Can I assign a static internal IP address to dataproc cluster's master node?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

I want to assign a static internal IP address to dataproc cluster master node. From [Google cloud official doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address) I know how to do such to a single VM. But does anyone know how to assign reserved internal IP address to the master node?

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the internal IP address for an existing resource, i.e. to a running VM instance. Instead, you should promote its ephemeral internal IP to a static one. So, when it restarts its internal IP will be the same. [These steps](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address#promote-in-use-internal-address) can guide you to do it, for example:

```
ysu@cloudshell:~ (project-id)$ gcloud compute instances describe cluster-b045-m --zone us-central1-a | grep "networkIP"     
  networkIP: 10.128.0.3     
ysu@cloudshell:~ (project-id)$ gcloud compute addresses create master-static-ip --addresses 10.128.0.3 --region us-central1 --subnet default     
  Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project-id/regions/us-central1/addresses/master-static-ip].
```

Maybe, what you want to do could be accomplished creating first a [custom VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/network#creating_a_cluster_that_uses_your_vpc_network), however I'm curious why you want to have an internal static IP, as the nodes in a Dataproc cluster are intended to workloads and their IPs are not so relevant in that sense.